# How to get permission for geolocation in webview without alert msg (iOS)?

Tags: javascript, ios, geolocation, uialertview

I've an app that load my website on webview. My website make use in geolocation API (by JS) to find user location. 
My question is after the application itselfs has permission to get user location can I disable the alert mesage of the webview and get location without ask the user again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your application has permission to get the user's location, can't it just pass that information on to your website as part of the initial URL (in the query string)?

Comment: Thanks. My "app" should run on mobile browser too. But you probebly right, there is no another way to get location without permission every time, as much as "Safari application" cann't. it has permission but it still need premission for each site.

Comment: @uriel: Your website can still ask for the geolocation data if it isn't passed that data in the URL (as it will be from your program), thus allowing it to work in any mobile browser.